# libgit2sharp.Patch outofmemory

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, git, out-of-memory, libgit2sharp

I try to use libgit2sharp.Patch to find how much line added or deleted, but i got an error while i try to run it. When i run my asp.net mvc project in debug mode, it doesn't have any problem, until i run it without debug mode, i got my web load too long and didn't show the page. When i run in debug mode again, finally an error appear from libgit2sharp.Patch variable with error message system.outofmemory. This is how i implement libgit2sharp.Patch

```
Patch treePatchInfo = repo.Diff.Compare<Patch>(firstTree, compareTree, null, compareOptions: compareOptions);
                    commitChangeValue = from s in treeChangeInfo
                                        let patch = treePatchInfo[s.Path]
                                        select new CommitChangeModel
                                        {
                                            ChangeKind = s.Status,
                                            LinesAdded = patch.LinesAdded,
                                            LinesDeleted = patch.LinesDeleted,
                                            OldPath = s.Path,
                                            Patch = patch.Patch,
                                            Path = s.Path
                                        };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in number of additions/removal per file, I'd suggest you to rather rely on the following construct would be more efficient.

```
var stats = repo.Diff.Compare<PatchStats>(...);
```

You can take a peek at **[PR #660](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/pull/610)** where it's been introduced to get a first grasp of its usage.

**Note:** Regarding the OOM Exception, we'd very interested in getting more information about it. Would you be so kind as to open an issue in the **[bug tracker](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/new)** so that we can get a deeper look at it?

Comment: It only work if i run my project in debug mode, but when i run it whit ctrl+f5 i got my localhost load in a long time and the page doesn't appear after that, i don't know it still in OOM or not because it only got an error when i run it not in debug mode, maybe you have another solution.